# Subscribe SwiftUI View to every update of a combine publisher

Tags: swiftui, combine

Here's a simplified example of an approach I want to take, but I can't get the simple example to work.

I have a Combine publisher who's subject is a view model State:

```
struct State {
    let a: Bool
    let b: Bool
    let transition: Transition?
}
```

The State includes a `transition` property. This describes the `Transition` that the `State` made in order to become the current state.

```
enum Transition {
    case onAChange, onBChange
}
```

I want to use `transition` property to drive animations in a `View` subscribed to the publisher so that different transitions animate in specific ways.

## View code

Here's the code for the view. You can see how it tries to use the `transition` to choose an animation to update with.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    let model: TestViewModel

    @State private var state: TestViewModel.State
    private var cancel: AnyCancellable?

    init(model: TestViewModel) {
        self.model = model
        self._state = State(initialValue: model.state.value)
        self.cancel = model.state.sink(receiveValue: updateState(state:))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("AAAAAAA").scaleEffect(state.a ? 2 : 1)
            Text("BBBBBBB").scaleEffect(state.b ? 2 : 1)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            model.invert()
        }
    }
    
    private func updateState(state: TestViewModel.State) {
        withAnimation(animation(for: state.transition)) {
            self.state = state
        }
    }

    private func animation(for transition: TestViewModel.Transition?) -> Animation? {
        guard let transition = transition else { return nil }

        switch transition {
        case .onAChange: return .easeInOut(duration: 1)
        case .onBChange: return .easeInOut(duration: 2)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(model: TestViewModel())
    }
}
```

## Model code

```
final class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var state = CurrentValueSubject<State, Never>(State(a: false, b: false, transition: nil))
    
    struct State {
        let a: Bool
        let b: Bool
        let transition: Transition?
    }
    
    enum Transition {
        case onAChange, onBChange
    }

    func invert() {
        let oldState = state.value
        setState(newState: .init(a: !oldState.a, b: oldState.b, transition: .onAChange))
        setState(newState: .init(a: !oldState.a, b: !oldState.b, transition: .onBChange))
    }
    
    private func setState(newState: State) {
        state.value = newState
    }
}
```

You can see in the model code that when `invert()` is called, *two* state changes occur. The model first toggles `a` using the `.onAChange` transition, and then toggles `b` using the `.onBChange` transition.

## What should happen

What should happen when this is run is that each time the view is clicked, the text "AAAAAAA" and "BBBBBBB" should toggle size. However, the "AAAAAAA" text should change quickly (1 second) and the "BBBBBBB" text should change slowly (2 seconds).

## What actually happens

However, when I run this and click on the view, the view doesn't update at all.

I can see from the debugger that `onTapGesture { … }` is called and `invert()` is being called on the model. Also `updateState(state:)` is also being called. However, `TestView` is not changing on screen, and `body` is not invoked again.

## Other things I tried

### Using a callback

Instead of using a publisher to send the event to the view, I've tried a callback function in the model set to the view's `updateState(state:)` function. I assigned to this in the `init` of the view with `model.handleUpdate = self.update(state:)`. Again, this did not work. The function `invert()` and `update(state:)` were called, as expected, but the view didn't actually change.

### Using `@ObservedObject`

I change the model to be `ObservableObject` with its `state` being `@Published`. I set up the view to have an `@ObservedOject` for the model. With this, the view *does* update, but it updates both pieces of text using the same animation, which I don't want. It seems that the two state updates are squashed and it only sees the last one, and uses the `transition` from that.

## Something that did work – sort of

Finally, I tried to directly copy the model's `invert()` function in to the view's `onTapGesture` handler, so that the view updates its own state directly. This did work! Which is  something, but I don't want to put all by model update logic in my view.

## Question

How can I have a SwiftUI view subscribe to *all* states that a model sends through its publisher so that it can use a `transition` property in the state to control the animation used for that state change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you subscribe a view to the publisher is by using `.onRecieve(_:perform:)`, so instead of saving a cancellable inside `init`, do this:

```
var body: some View {
   VStack(spacing: 20) {
      Text("AAAAAAA").scaleEffect(state.a ? 2 : 1)
      Text("BBBBBBB").scaleEffect(state.b ? 2 : 1)
   }
   .onTapGesture {
      model.invert()
   }
   .onReceive(model.state, perform: updateState(state:)) // <- here
}
```

Comment: That works! Brilliant – I totally thought I'd tried that and found it didn't work (it only updated the the final state so changed, but only used one animation). Thank you. … would you be able to extend your answer to explain why the other approaches don't work – either do nothing, or only update with the final state?

Comment: I haven't analyzed your other approaches in depth, but you should remember that a view is just a structure and SwiftUI can duplicate it and reinitialize however many times it wants, so a subscription done in init could happen for some copy of `TestView` -  not the one in the view hierarchy. Values have to be assigned to a `@State` property after init (or directly with `self._prop`).